# What is the difference between もので and ので for giving a reason?

Tags: word-choice

They both serve to indicate a cause/reason according to [goo.ne.jp](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/219908/meaning/m0u/%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7/).

Is there a nuance between them?

Comment: Can you give some examples?

Comment: もので:「時間がないもので、失礼する」
ので:「朝夕は冷えるので服装などに注意したい。」

Comment: I can’t say I’ve heard the first. Pretty much always the second. Not saying it’s grammatically correct, but I would say it’s definitely not common.

Comment: ^ But you surely have heard 「～もんで」「～もんだから」or「～もんですから」, right? 「すみません！急いでた**もんで** …。」とか・・

Comment: I've found that, regionally, もんで & だもんで can be more colloquially used than other equivalents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We usually use ～もので to give a reason as an (often rather personal or subjective) **excuse** (言い訳/弁解/弁明), while we more generally use ので to give a reason. 明鏡国語辞典 says:

> もので 〘接助〙
>   **言い訳**がましく理由を示す。…ものだから。
>   「貧乏所帯なもので、大したおかまいもできません」「気が弱いもので、断れません」

You might also hear ～ものですから in a politer conversation, eg 「初めてだったものですから、道に迷ってしまいました。」

<sub>(It can be ～も**ん**で, ～も**ん**だから, ～も**ん**ですから in colloquial speech.)</sub>

---

A few examples for comparison:

> ◎ 安かった**もので**、つい衝動買いしてしまった。<sub>(sounds like an excuse, more subjective)</sub>
>   ◎ 安かった**ので**、つい衝動買いしてしまった。<sub>(sounds like plainly giving a reason)</sub>
>
> ◎ 先週は行けなくてすみませんでした。熱があった**もので**・・・。
>   ◎ 先週は行けなくてすみませんでした。熱があった**ので**・・・。
>
> ◎ 明日は天気がいい**ので**、お花見に行く予定です。
>   ✖ 明日は天気がいい**もので**、お花見に行く予定です。
>
> ◎ あのケーキ屋さんはおいしいと評判な**ので**、一緒に行きましょう。
>   ✖ あのケーキ屋さんはおいしいと評判な**もので**、一緒に行きましょう。